# Codeigniter 4 registration to multiple table

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have some questions that I do not know how to solve it. Currently I have 2 tables, users and user_profile. I have 2 fields in users_profile, membership and coins which will be added by a default value "yes/no" for membership and "0" for coins.

1. How do I add "created_by" column from the form username?
2. How do I add the value in the user_profile table when the user submit the registration form?

This is my code that will store the registration form fields in users table

```
public function register()
{
    $data = [];
    helper(['form']);
    
    $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
    
    // To add in is_unique
    
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){
        //validations
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'required|is_unique[users.username]',
            'email' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'dob' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'contact' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
        
        $errors = [
            'username' => [
                'is_unique' => 'Username already exist!'
            ],
            'email' => [
                'is_unique' => 'Email already exist!'
            ]
        ];
        
        if(!$this->validate($rules, $errors)){
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        }else{
            //store information into database
            
            $model = new AccountModel();
            
            $newData = [
                'username' => $this->request->getVar('username'),
                'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'firstname' => $this->request->getVar('firstname'),
                'lastname' => $this->request->getVar('lastname'),
                'dob' => $this->request->getVar('dob'),
                'country' => $this->request->getVar('country'),
                'contact' => $this->request->getVar('contact'),
                'password' => $this->request->getVar('password'),
                'created_by' => $this->request->getVar('username')
            ];
            $model->save($newData);
            $user_id = $model->insertID();
            $newAccount = $model->where('user_id',$user_id)->first();
            $userProfileModel = new UserProfileModel();
            $newProfile = $userProfileModel->save(['user_id' => $user_id, 'coins' => '0', 'membership' => 'no']);
        }
    }
    
    echo view('templates/header', $data);
    echo view('account/register');
    echo view('templates/footer');
}
```

AccountModel

```
class AccountModel extends Model{
    
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'dob',
        'country',
        'contact',
        'password',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_by'
    ];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
    
    protected function beforeInsert(array $data) {
        
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
        
    }
    
    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data) {
        
        $data = $this->passwordHash($data);
        return $data;
        
    }
    
    protected function passwordHash(array $data){
        if(isset($data['data']['password']))
            $data['data']['password'] = password_hash($data['data']['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
    }
    
}
```

UserProfileModel

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserProfileModel extends Model{
    
    protected $table = 'user_profile';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'user_id',
        'coins',
        'membership'
    ];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
    
    protected function beforeInsert(array $data) {
        
    }
    
    protected function beforeUpdate(array $data) {
        
    }
    
    
}



?>
```

Comment: Well one thing you need to look at your $newdata in your controller and the allowed fields in your model. They do not match. And why the created_by when it is the same as the username you are saving in username?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thank you for your help and so sorry, I did not realized I made a mistake there, I have updated it. Why I want to save the username as created_by is because some accounts will be created by admin for some reasons. That's why I would want to know which account are created by users and which are created by admins for record purposes. So stupid of me without realizing I have made a stupid mistake. Now I'm left with point 2) that I can't figure out how

Answer (score 0):

1. **How do I add "created_by" column from the form username?**

- use `insertID()` ci4 models method aftaer `save` method executed. It will return the lastest primary key which been saved from the table you want. in this case from your account table

```
$model->save($newData);
$userId= $model->insertID();
```

2. **How do I add the value in the user_profile table when the user submit the registration form?**

- you should have a foreign key in **user_profile** table that refering to **users** table primary key

```
++++++++++++     ++++++++++++++++
+   users  +     + user_profile +
++++++++++++     ++++++++++++++++
+-id[p.k]  +     +-id[p.k]      +
+-username +     +-users_id[f.k]+
+-email    +     +-coins        +
+-email    +     +-membership   +
```

- get lastest user data by `$userId`, i assume your primary key is 'id' and than save to the user_profile

```
$newAccount = $model->where('id',$user_id')->first();

$userProfileModel = new UserProfileModel();

$newProfile = $userProfileModel->save(['user_id' => $userId])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and I am very new to Codeigniter 4. Appreciate if you could help me to understand. 1) $userId= $model->insertID(); this is getting the ID value and not the username from the table, right? 2) What do I need to do in the UserProfileModel function in my model? Because I can't understand whether your code does the same thing as what I need it to do. I have updated my current model in my question

Comment: 1. yes..bcz you craete `$model` as a `AccountModel()` when u call `$model->insertID()` it will return the Last insert ID from it.

2. i mean you can input the users id from your last register to the foreign key that refering to the users id or you can use your created_by field on it

Comment: I have updated my code in my question. Am I doing it  right? I tried to register and I get this error https://imgur.com/a/13AcNWz